# PHP send array with a redirect

Tags: php, arrays, redirect

Is it possible to send an array with a `header('Location:);` so the array can be echo'd after redirect? I have a signup form and on error it redirects to the homepage, on success it redirects to the member page. if I can do something like `$arr['error_message'] = 'Invalid Password';` then on the redirect `if (isset($arr['error_message'])) { echo $arr['error_message']; }`

This is to hopefully achieve not needing an extra URL parameter (&error=Invalid%20Login). I noticed `$_SESSION` is an option but what if the user has multiple tabs open? Or am I stuck with using more URL params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $_GET to do that, like

```
 if($success)
 {
     $msg="success";
     header("Location: member.php?msg=$msg");
 }
 else
 {
     $msg="Invalid Password";
     header("Location: home.php?msg=$msg"); 
 }
```

And retrive in you current page like

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']))
{ 
    echo $_GET['msg']; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest you few solutions.

**Solution 1**

GET Param (Indeed you says don't want to)
I don't see any issue with sending GET Param, since it doesn't contain any sensitive data. As an example you can use some internal CODEs for this.
Ex:
You define some codes.

```
$code = 1; // This should be dynamic like, 
           // 1 => When Password wrong, 
           // 2 => When login ID not exists, 
           // 3 => when unknown error occurred
header('Location: error.php?err=' . $code);
```

So in error.php you can check that.

```
$errorCode = $_GET['err'];

switch($errorCode)
{
   case 1;
   {
       echo "Password wrong";
       break;
   }
   case 2;
   {
       echo "login ID not exists";
       break;
   }
   // Add custom messages as you wish
}
```

**Solution 2**

Using session. I think it doesn't matter if you have multiple tabs. In your password checking code you can initiate the session before the redirection.

```
$_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE'] = "Whatever you want";
```

Then in your error.php (the redirected page) you can check that

```
if(isset($_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE'];
    unset($_SESSION['ERROR_MESSAGE']);
}
```

**Solution 3**

Instead of PHP redirect, you can generate hidden form with POST action and you can assign relevant error message to that when executing

```
<form name="frmError" id="frmError" method="POST" action="error.php">
<input type="hidden" name="error" value="<?php echo $errorMessage; ?>" />
</form>
```

And write a javascript function to POST your form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.frmError.submit();
}
</script>
```

Then modify your body tag as bellow

```
<body <?php if(isset($errorMessage)) {?> onload="submitform();" <?php } ?> >
```

Hope this will help you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Session is a common solution. Though user can open multiple tabs, you want that an user signup  an account in the same time. So it doesn't cause problems